# drupal wont open - gives a parse error

Tags: drupal

I was creating a module and had made a typo and then got a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in..." error. But now when I try to go to my drupal site it gives me this error even though I fixed it! I can't get into the site at all! How do I flush this error out of drupal so that I can restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You knew what you have been doing last to your module, comment all last inserted code and check than if your site works. If it works add code again, also check if that code is cashed for some reasons and clear cache.

Comment: Thanks, but there was no need to clear the cache. Someone pointed out that a parse error isn't cached. I re-wrote the file and it worked.